# Substracting from the left side of a string using R

Tags: r, replace

I want to extract the first 4, 7, or 10 characters from the left side of a string in a column of data. I tried `substrLeft(x,8)` it works for simple text, but my data looks like this `T*50:03:01:, T*01:01:01:06, T*08:04:01:01, T*201:01:01, T*414:01 etc`. I want the output to placed in a new column. To select the first 4 characters I used:

```
xST$New <-substr(T\\*.?, 1, 4, xST$Old)
```

and also tried gsub:

```
xST$New <-gsub("T*(.*?):(.*?); *$", "\\1", hlaST$A.1, perl = TRUE)
```

both commands are invalid.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract?

Comment: For example for string T*08:04:01:01 I want T*08:04 and T*08:04:01 to be extracted into 2 separate columns

Comment: I attempted an answer below, but what is your requirement if the input column be not long enough to have say 7 or 10 characters?  What happens then?

Comment: You could do something more complicated to get all segments:  `x <- c("T*414:01:01","T*50:03:01:")` and then `lapply(strsplit(x, ":"), function(v) Reduce(function(a,b) paste(a,b,sep=":"), v, accumulate=TRUE) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
xST$New_1 <- substr(xST$Old, 1, 7)
xST$New_2 <- substr(xST$Old, 1, 10)
```

If you want to extract a substring based on a specific pattern, then `sub()` might be more appropriate.  For example, if the input looked like `T*414:01:01` and you wanted to extract everything before the second colon, you could try:

```
xST$New <- sub("(.*?:.*?):.*", "\\1", xST$Old)
```

We can make the matching pattern more specific to your string if necessary.   The pattern above only counts colons, without regard to anything else.

Comment: Great it worked I did not know 'x' could be the column name. Is it possible to extract data before the first colon because I have also strings like this T*414:01:01 in the column and I would like to extract T*414:01.

Comment: @Mona Then you can try using `sub()` for that.  Let me update my answer.

Comment: The substring based on the colon pattern also worked.  Thank you.

Comment: I also have a string with this patteren in the same column T*36:20 how can I adjust the sub() formula to apply to all possible string patterns e.g T*01:01:01:01, T*03:05, T*461:01, T*36:20

Comment: What do you want to extract and why does my current answer not work?  Ideally, the inputs should fit the pattern.

Comment: The examples I described above I still want to extract characters before the first colon. xST$New <- sub("(.*?:.*?):.*", "\\1", xST$Old) does not work for T*36:20 as it has a different string pattern. However I could run  different scripts to cope with the various string patterns.

Comment: `xST$New <- sub("(.*?):.*", "\\1", xST$Old)`

Comment: Thank you, this script is perfect, I wrote a similar script but I inserted an additional ?  to give ST$New <- sub("(.*?):.?*", "\\1", xST$Old), hence why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For more simplified approach you could use the stringr library:

```html
x <- "T*08:04:01:01"

library(stringr)
str_sub(x, 1, 7)
[1] "T*08:04"
```

you could you `mutate` and incorporate the new column as part of a pipeline